# Iterate Row Selection Using Current Selection ArcMap 10.2 ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, iterator

I am trying to make a model using Iterate Row Selection. I have a buffer shapefile and a line shapefile. Ideally I would like for the model to loop through the buffer shapefile and select each row one by one.

When one of the buffer polygons is selection, I need to run a select by location using the current buffer selection to assign the FID of the buffer to a field called "FAF_FID" for the line shapefile

For example, if there are 3 line features with their centroid in Buffer FID 2, the three line features would be given a FAF_FID of 2.

I am looking for advice on how to accomplish this.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can post what you have already tried and what is not working, ie. if you are getting an error message or unexpected output, etc.

Comment: Do your buffers overlap each other?  Also, do some lines fall within multiple buffer zones?  I can see some issues with automating this if that's the case, because previous FAF_FID values could be overwritten down the line if multiple buffers cover a line feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The model you want is below:

You want to be using the Feature Selection iterator not the Row iterator. You set that up using the ID field as the case field. This is what becomes *Value* and this is what you use with in-line substitution in the field calculate tool.

But you should heed @Baltok's warning as if you have overlapping buffers then that will overwrite. The question you then need to be asking is how to filter those buffers, or may be you want to know all and then it becomes a concatenation of ID's?

[image: Model]

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I meant. I wasn't sure of how to use the Value from the Iterator but this explains all I needed to know. Appreciate it!

Comment: @ChlsG if my answer is the solution to your question please tick it as such. This informs others that your question had an answer and will help others searching for answers to their own problems.